# Component in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on react and want to specify href link to another component in react js.
Below is the href attribute I am working on and want to redirect to another component named MenuForm. This component has form for menu input. I want the form to be open after I click Menu link.

`<a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">Menu</a>`

Component I want to redirect is MenuForm
`<MenuForm />`

Comment: Could you precise what you are looking for? You want to redirect to an other component when you click on a link? Do you use `react-router`?

Comment: I am new to React. My form is in MenuForm component and I want to load the form when I press Menu button

Comment: This is what you need

https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html

 <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>Rendering with React</Link>


For ref : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: You have provided way too little context. It can be as simple as adding `onClick` to the link element that updates internal state (e.g. `this.setState({ showMenuForm: true })`, and in `render()` something like `{this.state.showMenuForm && <MenuForm /> }` ), or as complicated as adding router, redux, and God knows what else to the app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a state to show/hide your form:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    showForm: false
  }

  handleClick = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({showForm: true})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick} className="btn btn-primary">Menu</a>
      // ...
      {this.state.showForm && <MenuForm />}
    )
  }
}
```

If you use [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), it's even simplier:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false)

  function handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    setShowForm(true)
  }

  return (
    <a href="#" onClick={handleClick} className="btn btn-primary">Menu</a>
    // ...
    {showForm && <MenuForm />}
  )
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react-router-dom` and want the url to change when you click the link, you can setup your router like this,

```
// router.js
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/here" component={HereComponent} />
    <Route path="/there" component={ThereComponent} />
  </BrowserRouter>,
);
```

Then you should be able to Use the `Link` Component like,

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
<Link to="/there">there</Link>
```

This will load the component and change the browser URL. You can read more about react-router-dom here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start